# How to set route filters on ui.router states?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In Laravel, setting route filters is quite easy. We use a `beforeFilter([])` and specify which functions in the controller should be accessible on authentication, and also have `except` in exceptional scenarios.

Now, I just started using Angular's `ui.router` and the concept of states is certainly the way forward, but I am asking a asking a noob question here. How do I set route filters on my states. I definitely don't want to do it on individual routes using `resolve`.

Here's some code. This is what I use for my profile route. I use `resolve` to make sure it is only accessible when authenticated. But the problem is, my login and signup routes are still accessible when I am logged in. They shouldn't be. It should just redirect to home.

Now I could add resolves to states I don't want accessible when I am logged in, but is that the right way?  What if there are many. That would be repeating code. Is there a 'ui.router` way to do this?

```
.state('profile', {
                url: '/profile',
                templateUrl: 'js/app/partials/profile.html',
                controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    authenticated: function($q, $location, $auth) {
                        var deferred = $q.defer();

                        if (!$auth.isAuthenticated()) {
                            $location.path('/login');
                        } else {
                            deferred.resolve();
                        }

                        return deferred.promise;
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: why dont you listen to events like `$stateChangeStart` and do what you trying to do in here like `authentication`.

Comment: Can you supply an example @K.Toress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one way is to create a service which does your validation and then in a run block you would call that service on any `$stateChangeStart` events as K.Toress mentioned.

If you want to specify which states need authenticating, for example, you can use the data option in your state definition config to define whether or not it needs authenticating. So to define a state that needs auth you could try something like...

```
$stateProvider
  .state('foo', {

    templateUrl: 'foo.html',

    // etc...

    data: {
        requiresAuth: true
    } 

  });
```

You can then check this in your `$stateChangeStart` event which gets passed a `toState` argument from which you can access the `data` properties.

```
var app = angular.module('foo', ['ui.router'])

.factory('RouteValidator', ['$rootScope', '$auth', function($rootScope){

  return {
    init: init
  };

  function init(){
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', _onStateChangeStart);
  }

  function _onStateChangeStart(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){


    // check the data property (if there is one) defined on your state 
    // object using the toState param

    var toStateRequiresAuth = _requiresAuth(toState),

        // if user is not authenticated and the state he is trying to access
        // requires auth then redirect to login page

        if(!$auth.isAuthenticated() && toStateRequiresAuth){
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go('login');
            return;
        }

  }

  function _requiresAuth(toState){
        if(angular.isUndefined(toState.data) || !toState.data.requiresAuth){
            return false;
        }
        return toState.data.requiresAuth;
    }

}])

.run(['RouteValidator', function(RouteValidator){
  // inject service here and call init()
  // this is so that you keep your run blocks clean 
  // and because it's easier to test the logic in a service than in a 
  // run block
  RouteValidator.init();
}]);
```

**EDIT**

Okay I've made a very basic [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/z0P7QlagxGYbd9HHbkVe?p=preview) on plunker that will hopefully show the concept. I'll post the code here too. Help this helps.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider){

  $stateProvider

    .state('public', {
      url: "/public",
      templateUrl: "public.html"
    })

    .state('login', {
      url: "/login",
      templateUrl: "login.html",
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
      }
    })

    .state('admin', {

      url: "/admin",
      templateUrl: "admin.html",

      data: {
        requiresAuth: true
      },

      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
      }

    });

}]);

app.factory('User', [function(){
  return {
    isAuthenticated: false
  };
}]);

app.factory('RouteValidator', ['$rootScope', 'User', '$state', function($rootScope, User, $state){

  return {
    init: init
  };
  /////////////////////////////////

  function init(){
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', _onStateChangeStart);
  }

  function _onStateChangeStart(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){

     var toStateRequiresAuth = _requiresAuth(toState);

    if(!User.isAuthenticated && toStateRequiresAuth){
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('public');
        alert('You are not authorised to see this view');

        return;
    }

  }

  function _requiresAuth(toState){
      if(angular.isUndefined(toState.data) || !toState.data.requiresAuth){
          return false;
      }
      return toState.data.requiresAuth;
  }

}]);

app.run(['RouteValidator', function(RouteValidator){
  RouteValidator.init();
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.2/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.2"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@0.2.15" data-semver="0.2.15" src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.15/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <a ui-sref="public">public</a>
    <a ui-sref="login">login</a>
    <a ui-sref="admin">admin</a>
    <div ui-view></div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there something like this inbuilt in ui-router?

Comment: Not as far as I know. ui.router just gives you the  '$stateChangeStart' event and you can use that to achieve what you want.

Comment: Ah that's a pity. Can you please give me a full example to help me get kick started. Ideally I was wishing to supply an array of states I want authenticated and an array of states I want accessible when non-authenticated such that if you visit login and signup pages after you're logged in, you just go back to home.

Comment: You can specify that a state needs to be authenticated using the data property in the sate configuration object used to defined each state. I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Turns out, it had to be this `.factory('RouteValidator', ['$rootScope', '$auth', function($rootScope, $auth){`..Thanks @Matt for your help. I think this is a good starting point. If you think this can be done better, let me know. So far I am going to be using this technique.

Comment: Nice one, by the way, how to I get the user back to the previous state. Say, he is logged in, and is on profile state, but clicks login, since that login page won't open as he's logged in, he should be back on profile. Any way we can achieve that easily with `ui.router` states?

Comment: Yeah the $auth is a reference to the Satellizer auth service I use. See https://github.com/sahat/satellizer